# How to Add new line without using \n in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, printing

I am a beginner, I am trying To make a program which inputs a name and prints name in `*` (star) pattern,
I defined function A and B which return `*` pattern Of A and B, But when i combine them to print
they print in new line, I want to print them in same line. I tried print argument `end=''` or `sep=''` but
it is not working.

```
def A(size = 10):
    final = str()
    height = size
    breath = size
    
    space1 = breath
    space2 = 1
    
    midline = int(height/2) + 2 #adjust the position of miline
    
    for x in range(1,height+1):
        if x == 1 :
            s = ' '*space1 + '*'
            
        elif x == midline :
            s = ' '*space1 + '*' + '*'*space2 + '*'
            space2 = space2 + 2
            
        else :
            s = ' '*space1 + '*' + ' '*space2 + '*'
            space2 = space2 + 2
        space1 = space1 - 1
        final = final + '\n' + s
    return final

def B(size=10):
    final = str()
    height = size
    breath = size
    space = breath - 2
    curve = 3
    
    for x in range(1,height+1):
        if x == (height//2 + 1):
            s = '*'*(breath - curve)
            s = s + ' '*(breath-len(s))
            
        elif x == 1 or x == height:
            s = '*' * (breath-curve)
            s = s + ' '*(breath-len(s))
            
        elif x == 2 or x == (height-1):
            s = '*'+ ' '*(breath-curve) + '*'
            s = s + ' '*(breath-len(s))
            
        elif x == (height//2 + 1)-1 or x == (height//2 + 1)+1:
            s = '*'+ ' '*(breath-curve) + '*'
            s = s + ' '*(breath-len(s))
            
        else:
            s = '*' + ' '*space + '*'
            s = s + ' '*(breath-len(s))
            
        final = final + '\n' + s
    return final
              
print(B())
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to combine the outputs of `A()` and `B()` to print "AB", i.e., adjacent to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print them like, `AA` or `AB` then you would need to change the logic. Because when you call a single `A()` python will print it with all the `newlines` you have used. You can do something like the following

```
def A(size=10):
    final = str()
    height = size
    breath = size

    space1 = breath
    space2 = 1

    midline = int(height / 2) + 2  # adjust the position of miline

    for x in range(1, height + 1):
        if x == 1:
            s = ' ' * space1 + '*' + ' ' * space1

        elif x == midline:
            s = ' ' * space1 + '*' + '*' * space2 + '*' + ' ' * space1
            space2 = space2 + 2

        else:
            s = ' ' * space1 + '*' + ' ' * space2 + '*' + ' ' * space1
            space2 = space2 + 2
        space1 = space1 - 1
        final = final + '\n' + s
    return final

a1 = A().split('\n')
a2 = A().split('\n')

for i in range(len(a1)):
    print(a1[i] + a2[i])
```

I have modified `A()` here. Here I have fetched the letter then split them using `\n`. Then Concatenate each of the lines and print. When creating a letter, use the same number of spaces after the last star you have printed in a line.

[image]